# Input tag with type number to allow pass a Number and Floating values with one decimal point iin jsp , javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to enter number and float values in my text box used in jsp page Here, dont want to include negative number only positive numbers to use.

```
function validatenumber(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode(key);
  //var regex = /^[0-9\b]+$/; // allow only numbers [0-9]
  var regex = /^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/; //allow nummber and decimal point [ex: 0.5, 0.06,0.007, 0.0004]

  if (!regex.test(key)) {

    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if (theEvent.preventDefault)
      theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<input class='givenWeight' type='number' value='0'  maxlength='5' name='givenWeight' onKeyPress='validatenumber(event);' >
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "onkeypress". Use "onchange" instead.

By do this, you can check the input everytime the input value changed.

If the input value is illegal, just set the value to the previous value.

For example, this is a demo to check weather the value is a integer.

```js
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
var preValue = input.value;
function checkvalue() {
  if (/^\d*$/.test(input.value)) {
    preValue = input.value;
    input.value = input.value;
  } else {
    input.value = preValue;
    alert("illegal input!");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onchange="checkvalue()" />
```

Comment: If in the input decimal value with one point and whole number between 1 to 100 must be handled then how can i do ?

Comment: It's just a matter of Regexp. You can try this:
/^[1-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]*$|$)/